# My ajax script will run once correctly but it wont run again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, authentication

So I seem to be having some issues with my code. Now I have just started learning AJAX and jquery so I am very new at it. They way the the site works is:

When a user clicks the Login button a form will appear under the button where they enter a username and password. When the user clicks login my ajax script will handle logging them in and refreshing their avatar so they know they are logged in. Then when they want to log out they click logout and it logs them out no problem.

The problem I am having is once I have run through the login/logout process I am unable to get the form to show up again without refreshing the page.

I hope I made sense =/ Here is the code I have:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/jscript"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'loginsystem/login.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function () {
            $("#loginForm").slideUp('slow');
            $("#playerFace").load('ajaxPHPScripts/getUserAvatar-100px.php');
            $("#loginLogout").load('ajaxPHPScripts/loginLogoutButton.php');
        }
      });
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
function doSomething() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'loginsystem/logout.php',
        success: function () {
            $("#playerFace").load('ajaxPHPScripts/getUserAvatar-100px.php');
            $("#loginLogout").load('ajaxPHPScripts/loginLogoutButton.php');
        }
      });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loginForm").hide();
  $("#loginbtn").click(function(){
    $("#loginForm").slideToggle('slow');
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#removeLoginForm").click(function(){
        $("#loginForm").slideUp('slow');
    });
});
</script>
```

Now for the html:

```
<div id="sidebar">
            <div id="sidebarinner">
                <div id="sidebarInnerInner">
                    <div id="playerAvatar">
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                          <tr>
                            <td style="width:100px;" id="playerFace"><img src="https://minotar.net/avatar/steve/100"></td>
                            <td style="text-align:center;"><?php ServerPing(); //pings to see if server is online?></td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div id="joinAndLog">
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="text-align:center; height:100%;">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width:50%;" id="loginLogout"><?php LoginOrLogout(); ?></td>
                                <td style="width:50%;"><?php SignupOrManageAcc(); ?></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>

                    <div id="loginForm">
                        <form class="sideForm" id="testform" style="text-align:center;  margin-bottom:10px;"> 
                            <input type="text" id="name" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username..."/> 
                            <br />
                            <input type="password" id="pass" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password..."/> 
                            <br />
                            <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" style="width:25%; cursor:pointer;" /> 
                            <input type="reset" name="" value="Cancle" id="removeLoginForm" style="width:25%; cursor:pointer;" />
                            <br />
                            <!--a href="#" style="padding:0px; margin:0px;">Forgot Password</a-->
                        </form> 
                     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind the newly loaded form the same way you did the first form.

So, after you load in the new HTML, you need to run something like this again:

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
  $.ajax({
    ///// snip /////
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Since this inside function is repeated, you might as well define it outside.

I.e.

```
var onFormSubmit = function (e) {
  $.ajax({
    ///// snip /////
  });
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Now to bind the form to that function, you simply do:

$('form').on('submit', onFormSubmit);

Comment: would this only get the form to work once before it messes up again? Or will it keep the form working? Im gonna give it a try but Id just like to hear what you have to say =)

Comment: That should be inside your success function, so every time a new form is loaded in, it is bound. You probably want to define this function elsewhere btw... I'll edit my answer with details on what I mean.

Comment: Ohhhh this makes sense! Thank you so very much! So basicly it will be a loop? Just not using any while, for, or do while

Comment: Not exactly a loop... well a manual loop if you want.

Basically the current problem is that you have a form, and you tell the browser to do something special when the form is submitted (that's what `$('form').on('submit', ...)` does). When you do your ajax thing, you're loading a new form into the page. The browser doesn't know what to do when this new form is submitted, so you need to tell it.

Comment: You can also use delegated event handlers as @jfriend00 suggested, if you wish... it's a bit more efficient for the browser I believe (though the difference is negligible in this situation), but also it's a new concept to learn so I spared you the extra complexity. :)

Comment: Ah ok that clears things up. So basically I have to tell the browser that every time I load a new form I have to do something with it.

Comment: haha yeah im still struggling with ajax in general. ill get it thanks for the help! =)

Comment: Yup, basically... assuming you have something special to do with your new form, which you do. :) No problem glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

If you're loading content dynamically, then you need to either rebind the static event handlers to the object in the dynamically loaded content or you need to use delegated event handlers that will still work on the dynamically loaded content.  The delegated event handlers are the more elegant solution.

A delegated event handler would look like this:

```
$('#sidebar').on('submit', '#loginForm', function() {...});
```

Ideally, you'd put an id (I suggested `"loginForm"` in my code example on the specific login form and use that instead of `"form"` for the target selector so you know the event handler targets only the correct form.

Using delegated event handling that is bound to a parent element that is not dynamically created/destroyed, but a select that targets the specific dynamic content inside that static parent allows you to keep the event handler in force even if the target content is destroyed and then reloaded.

Comment: Ah I will have to read up on delegated event handlers. As far as the form selector would it work if I did `form#randomId` ?

Comment: @TomasCordero - There's no reason to use `form#randomId`.  Ids are unique in the page so there's no reason to precede them with anything else.  Just pick a meaningful and descriptive name for the form and use that.  That's why I suggested `"#loginForm"`.

Answer (score 0):

Updated code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#loginForm").hide();
 $("#loginbtn").on('click',function(){ // use .on() method
 $("#loginForm").slideToggle('slow');
});
});
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#removeLoginForm").on('click',(function(){ // use .on() method
 $("#loginForm").slideUp('slow');
});
});
```